# Joomla print page location file to change the format

Tags: joomla

In joomla 1.5.23 I want to remove the date icon and first horizontal line between title and date.Also there are two horizontal line between date and content where as I need only one line.How can I aligned the logo to the right? Actually I want to know the print and pdf file location in joomla so that I can customize the content according to my design.My site link is http://www.musiclibrary.fi.In home page content right side print and pdf icon.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox and the Firebug extension are the tools of choice for most web developers / web designers in answering these kinds of questions. With the inspect tool you can point at pretty much any aspect of the page and see the html source and the css affecting that element. You can see which file the css is in and even which line you need to edit.

You can test different settings by editing the css parameters 'live' in front of your eyes. When you have the right combination of settings you'll know what edit to make, in which file and on which line.

PS: The url you supplied is broken so I couldn't see the site to examine the specifics for you.